# SonarQube v5.6.6 Rest API - insufficient privileges

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to connect the SonarQube Community Plugin (from IntellIJ IDEA) to a local SonarQube instance, but looks like my users lack privileges to access the API. While trying to connect I get:

```
Cannot fetch SonarQube project and modules from SonarQube at mobilex.intra

org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 403 on https://qube.my.local/api/components/search?qualifiers=TRK : {"errors":[{"msg":"Insufficient privileges"}]}     
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseResponse.failIfNotSuccessful(BaseResponse.java:36)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseService.call(BaseService.java:55)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseService.call(BaseService.java:50)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.component.ComponentsService.search(ComponentsService.java:58)
    at org.intellij.sonar.sonarserver.SonarServer.getAllProjects(SonarServer.java:137)
    at org.intellij.sonar.sonarserver.SonarServer.getAllProjectsAndModules(SonarServer.java:110)
    at org.intellij.sonar.configuration.ResourcesSelectionConfigurable$DownloadResourcesRunnable.run(ResourcesSelectionConfigurable.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:247)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:750)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$10(ApplicationImpl.java:565)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Works fine while using an administrative account - but I don't want that. What privilege is needed to allow a common user to access the API and how do I apply it?

Comment: You may require the user to provide a username and a password.

Comment: Well, username and password _IS_ provided. The question actually is, what privilege is needed?

Comment: Are you sure /components/search is part of the 5.6.6. release? Looking at the documentation it is supported in > 6.3

Comment: @JeroenHeier i'm not 100% sure, what you are pointing me to. Do you mean the Community Plugin needs some newer version of SonarQube?

Comment: @Rob On the first exception line i see "https://qube.my.local/api/components/search" it i not clear who is calling that.